C# Проблема с кодировкой
При использовании кириллицы программа не читает ключевые слова, постоянно выдаёт "Извини, я не совсем понял твой ответ." Но, как только меняю ключевые слова на латиницу, сразу же работает корректно. Пробовал прописывать Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, но тоже не помогает.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    
    static Dictionary<string, string> responseDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"хорошо", "Я рад за тебя!" },
        {"плохо", "Не расстраивайся, все наладится."},
        {"отлично", "Прекрасно, я рад этому!"}
    };


    static void Main()
    {
         Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("Как у тебя дела?");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (responseDict.ContainsKey(userInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(responseDict[userInput]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Извини, я не совсем понял твой ответ.");
        }
    }
}


Может попробовать установить Console.InputEncoding, а не Console.OutputEncoding? У тебя же ввод.

Попробовал Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"), всё равно не помогает.

А другие кодировки пробовал? Например Unicode или UTF-16? Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16");

Действительно, UTF-16 сработало. Благодарю!

А не пробовали вообще не выставлять кодировку вручную? По идее системная (дефолтная) настройка должна быть подходящая для вашей системы.

Пробовал изначально, так не работало.
